# Angular ng-click in different controller is not working

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller called **ProductCtrl** and **Product.html** page. I want to mention inline ng-click in **Product.html** page. But, inline ng-click to different controller is not working. My code is as follows,

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('ProductdetailsCtrl', function($scope) { 

  $scope.showMe = function() {
    alert("button clicked");    
  }
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="ProductCtrl">
    <button ng-click="ProductdetailsCtrl.showMe()">Press  me</button>    
</div>
```

Comment: The showMe() function is a property of $scope, not a property of ProductdetailsCtrl. And there is no ProductdetailsCtrl variable in the scope either. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Why don't you put the method in the scpe of the ProductCtrl?

Comment: Because ProductCtrl populates list of products from where I wanna select specific product to show details of the selected product.

Comment: That's not a good reason. What's the problem with `ng-click="showDetailOf(product)"`?

Comment: Actually, According to my way of doing project  wanted to create a common ProductdetailsCtrl. Anyway, Now I see that I have change the application structure.... Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't a wrapping tag that use the ProductdetailsCtrl controller, You have to add ng-controller to the button like this:

```html
    <div ng-controller="ProductCtrl">
        <button ng-controller="ProductdetailsCtrl" ng-click="showMe()">Press  me</button>    
    </div>
```

If you already have declared a wrapping tag with the controller I suggest to use the a controller's variable. Like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('ProductdetailsCtrl', function() { 
    var vm = this;
    vm.showMe = function() {
        alert("button clicked");    
    };
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="ProductdetailsCtrl as ctrl1">
    <div ng-controller="ProductCtrl">
        <button ng-click="ctrl1.showMe()">Press  me</button>    
    </div>
</div>
```